# 3 hats paper ball

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

I received a page in the mail box, crumpled, there are 3 hats stickers on that.

```
RED HAT.    YELLOW HAT.
                          BLUE HAT.
```

What does that mean?

Each one Is a Classic Trillby

Comment: Removed the unsolved-mysteries tag, and replaced it with the enigmatic-puzzle tag. Feel free to undo the edit if I'm wrong.